# Detecting when a new row is added to grid [EXTJS]

Tags: extjs, grid, extjs4

I'm currently working on a project where I'm using ExtJS 4. Since I cannot find any solution to this problem I would like to know:

How do detect when a row is added to a grid?

Some solutions say I should be working on the grid while others propose to work on the store. I have tried to use datachanged and rowedit event on the store but nothing changed.

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean detect a new row being added? Are you referring to loading a new row from a server? Is the user pressing a button to add a new row?

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to the [`add`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.AbstractStore-event-add) event [`store`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.Store) that is bind to [`grid`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel).

There you discovered that there are new rows on the grid if you added it and did not sync with the server.

See the **sample** below:

```
Ext.define('Admin.view.credit.Grid', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    xtype: 'credit-grid',
    store: 'creditStore'
    listeners: {
        boxready: function(){
            var me =this;
            me.getStore().on('add',Ext.bind(me.onAddLines,me));
        }
    },
    onAddLines: function(store, records, index, eOpts){
        console.log('New Records Added');
        console.log(records);
    },
    rowLines: false,
    scrollable: false,
    columns: [{
        dataIndex: 'id',
        text: 'Id',
        flex: 0.5,
        sortable: false,
        groupable: false,
        hideable: false
    }]
});
```

[Add Event Documentation](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.AbstractStore-event-add)

Comment: Except the code you posted won't work at all... I assume you mean `this.getStore().on('add', .....);`

Comment: This code works, sometimes you need to modify the behavior of the application, based on the records you added.

Comment: No it doesn't. `getStore()` doesn't take any parameters. The event name is never passed to `on`.